# how to replace nan value with lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, nan

I want to replace nan values with a lambda layer in Tensorflow. I write the below code and it replaces nan data with 0 but when I pass it to next layer they are all nan!!! can anyone say why this happened and how to fix it?

```
# split into train test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
t = MinMaxScaler()
t.fit(X_train)
X_train = t.transform(X_train)
X_test = t.transform(X_test)
# define model
visible = Input(shape=(n_inputs,))
before_lambda_model = Model(visible, visible, name="before_lambda_model")
e1 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.is_nan(x)), x, 0))(visible)
after_lambda_model = Model(visible, e1, name="after_lambda_model")
output = Dense(n_inputs)(e1)
after_lambda_model2 = Model(visible, output, name="after_lambda_model")
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test,X_test))
p = model.predict(X)

m1 = before_lambda_model.predict(X)
m2 = after_lambda_model.predict(X)
m3 = after_lambda_model2.predict(X)
m1,m2.m3
```

resualt:

```
m1 = (array([[ 0.21534143,  2.939421  ,  0.6070648 , ..., -1.2343541 ,
          1.7189204 ,  0.2322954 ],
        [        nan,  3.4668574 , -2.365954  , ...,  0.8618614 ,
          2.0272305 ,  1.7704849 ],
        [-0.5045265 , -6.8411074 , -1.6613791 , ..., -0.89379954,
          2.2879124 , -1.1259099 ],
        ...,
        [ 2.5370893 ,  3.0216992 ,  0.02399945, ..., -0.23845583,
         -0.09022954, -0.8587186 ],
        [-0.7871305 , -3.2095814 , -0.9872522 , ...,  0.455077  ,
         -0.2627696 , -2.1793683 ],
        [-0.6270084 ,  4.0463853 , -1.293341  , ..., -0.16465937,
          1.908124  , -0.35484752]], dtype=float32),
m2 =  array([[ 0.21534143,  2.939421  ,  0.6070648 , ..., -1.2343541 ,
          1.7189204 ,  0.2322954 ],
        [ 0.        ,  3.4668574 , -2.365954  , ...,  0.8618614 ,
          2.0272305 ,  1.7704849 ],
        [-0.5045265 , -6.8411074 , -1.6613791 , ..., -0.89379954,
          2.2879124 , -1.1259099 ],
        ...,
        [ 2.5370893 ,  3.0216992 ,  0.02399945, ..., -0.23845583,
         -0.09022954, -0.8587186 ],
        [-0.7871305 , -3.2095814 , -0.9872522 , ...,  0.455077  ,
         -0.2627696 , -2.1793683 ],
        [-0.6270084 ,  4.0463853 , -1.293341  , ..., -0.16465937,
          1.908124  , -0.35484752]], dtype=float32),
m3 = array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32))
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question in case somebody has the same problem.
this leakage is because I pass x_train for both x and y in model.fit, which is correct for autoencoder models but in this case, I remove nan data of x_train in x position but do not remove nan data of x_tarin in y position. to fix this you should pass data without nan in the y position.

model.fit(*X_train*, *X_train*, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=2, validation_data=(*X_test*,*X_test*))